# Still getting warning "Deprecated API Usage from App Store Team"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, itms-90809

Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of new apps that use UIWebView - From App Store Team.

I'm not getting any results searching for UIWebView in my iOS app in Xcode, but still i'm getting   warning "Deprecated API Usage".

How to fix this issues.

Comment: check the library you are using, Facebook sdk etc

Comment: You might be using some third party library and in which they are using webview

Answer (score 2):

you can use grep command to find the  usage of webview in your project in any of your frameworks used

```
grep -r UIWebView  <project folder path>
```

on your project folder