# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage Error is coming- but I am not using wkwebview in my app. Please help to resolve this?

Tags: swift, app-store

On uploading app I am getting this error ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - but I am not using wkwebview in my app. Please help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage is related to `UIWebview` not `WKWebView`

If you are not using `UIWebview` directly in your project then one or more of the frameworks used in the project may be using it . In my case one of the third party was using UIWebView

You can check which Thirdpart is using it by grep command in terminal

```
grep -r UIWebview <path of your project Directory>
```

Comment: You gave the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60734708/1187415). – In cases where you *know* that the question has been asked and answered before it is better to leave a comment and/or flag the question as a duplicate, so that others (with sufficient reputation) can close the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I used this command it didn't show any results. It means my project doesn't contain it. Can you suggest some other solution?